# Reasons for using DNxHD instead of ProRes?

Tags: video-quality, codec, encoding, compression

I often use [**ProRes**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_ProRes) or [**DNxHD**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNxHD_codec) codec without any thoughts, because the quality is very similar, even though the code and the compression algorithm certainly is very different.

I would like to know **in which real world scenarios it makes more sense to use ProRes or DNxHD technically** to achieve the best quality?

Comment: If you're using a windows machine then that's a good reason to use DNxHD.

Comment: Thanks @stib. Makes sense. Other reasons?

Answer (score 1):

I have used both on my Ninja Blade with my C100, no real difference in quality across drastically different circumstances (night vs day). Pro Res works better on Mac, DNXHD works better on Windows. It all comes down to your OS, and whether you have to share the files with broadcasters (in which case I would use DNX as a lot of editors use Avid).

Other then that, I haven't heard, or seen first hand any differences between the two and I can honestly say that any differences pointed out online are mostly conjecture.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Alex +1! The operating system does not matter in my case... In the meantime, as you mentiond, I've also found that DNxHD is frequently used by broadcasters, but I'd like to know when I should use it in terms of quality. I'll accept the answer, if no one comes up with another one. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm interested too to be honest, so I actually did some research, the best article I could find that remotely addressed the difference was a non scientific test. Comments are interesting however, but still, nothing convincing. http://www.fallenempiredigital.com/blog/2013/02/28/avid-dnxhd-vs-apple-prores-vs-gopro-cineform-recompression-generation-loss/